# Getting Backing Bean From Converter from Faces Converter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, composite-component

I have a ccomposite compenent which contains SelectOneMenu Control and it's Backing Bean to Load Data of SelectOneMenu Control . And also have a custom converter for SelectOneMEnu control.   Now I want to get BackingBean from 'getAsObject' method of FacesConverter.  So  When I post the page component doesn't bind the value to  CDI beans field. My Converter and other codes are below.

This is the Converter Class.

```
@FacesConverter(value = "AccountConverter", forClass=Account.class)
public class AccountConverter implements Converter 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent uiComponent, String arg2) 
    {

        ValueExpression vex = ctx.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(ctx.getELContext(),"#{AccountComponent}", AccountComponent.class);

        AccountComponent accComponent = (AccountComponent)vex.getValue(ctx.getELContext());             
         Account racc=accComponent.GetAccount(Integer.valueOf(arg2)); // This methos returns Null
            return racc;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object account) {

         Account accctemp=((Account)account);
         Integer accid=accctemp.getAccountId();
         return accid.toString();

    }

}
```

The problem is ; I can not get the BackingBean ( AccountComponent) of composite control. **I mean 'vex.getValue' method returns NUll.**  And because of this reason I can not access to selected object of SelectOneMenu control.   My all other codes are below.

He Composite control.

```
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <cc:interface componentType="AccountComponent">
        <cc:attribute name="value" type="com.abank.pojo.Account" shortDescription="Account Class" />
        <cc:attribute name="CurrencyCode" />    
        <cc:attribute name="CurrencyCode" />            
        <cc:attribute name="ajaxEventListener" method-signature="void f1(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)" />
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <f:event type="postAddToView" listener="#{cc.init}" />
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="selec2.css" target="head" />         
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="select2.full.js" target="head" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="AccountComponent.js" target="head" />


        <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel value="Hesap" />
                <div></div>

          <h:selectOneMenu id="drpAccount"  width="75%" 
             value="#{cc.attrs.value}"   
            converter="AccountConverter"
            styleClass="form-control">
            <f:selectItems var="myaccount" value="#{cc.accounts}"
                itemLabel="#{myaccount.ibanNumber}" itemValue="#{myaccount}" />


        </h:selectOneMenu>
        </div>





    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

**BackingBean of Composite Control.**

```
@FacesComponent("AccountComponent")
public class AccountComponent extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {



    private List<Account> accounts;



    public void init() {
        String attr = this.getAttributeValue("CurrencyCode", "ALL");
        accounts=AccountRepo.AccountComponentLoadDataFromService(attr);
    }

    public Account GetAccount(Integer id) {

        if (id == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("no id provided");
        }
        if (accounts == null)
            return null;
        for (Account acc : accounts) {
            if (id.equals(acc.getAccountId())) {
                return acc;

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return("javax.faces.NamingContainer");
    }




    // Helpers
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
    private <T> T getAttributeValue(String key, T defaultValue) {
        T value = (T) getAttributes().get(key);
        return (value != null) ? value : defaultValue;
    }

    public String GetJsonFromObject() {

        return this.toString();

    }
    // Getters/setters
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        mapper.setDateFormat(df);
        String jsonInString = "";
        try {
            jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(this.accounts);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return jsonInString;
    }



    public List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return accounts;
    }

    public void setAccounts(List<Account> accounts) {
        this.accounts = accounts;
    }


}
```

And Last one is my JSf page where I use the component.

```
 <my:AccountComponent id="drpSourceAccount" 
                 CurrencyCode="YTL"                 
                 value="#{moneyOrderBean.sourceAccount}" >
                 </my:AccountComponent>
```

Comment: why not add a 'binding' attribute to the selectOneMenu and use that in the converter to access it? But I feel your solution is overly complicated. The converter already IS on the selectOneMenu, so why do you need to access its selected value? Or do I miss something (it is late friday afternoon so that could very well be possible))

Comment: Hi , where and how should use it ? If I use   binding  do I need to create a UIInput  variable in backing bean ?